# Another argument for a line being tangent to a circle in plane geometry

Tags: geometry

Here is a proposition that I saw presented in a plane geometry textbook. The argument in the textbook was unusually awkward.  I think that there is a simple argument for it.  I would appreciate comments to the demonstration that I am providing.

$\overline{AB}$ is a chord in a circle, and $\ell$ is a line that is tangent to the circle at $P$. $\ell$ is parallel to $\overline{AB}$ if, and only if, $\arc{AP} = \arc{BP}$.

Demonstration of "Only If"

$\overline{AB}$ and $\ell$ are parallel, and $k$ is the line through $P$ that is perpendicular to $\ell$. $k$ contains the center $O$ of the circle, and so, $k = \dvec{OP}$. $k$ is perpendicular to $\dvec{AB}$, too. If $M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$, $\dvec{OM}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{AB}$. There is only one line through $O$ that is perpendicular to $\overline{AB}$. So, $k = \dvec{OM} = \dvec{OP}$.

$\triangle{AOM} \cong \triangle{BOM}$. If $\overline{PQ}$ is a diameter of the circle,
\begin{equation*}
{\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOQ} = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOM} = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{BOM} = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{BOQ} .
\end{equation*}
By the definition of angular measure, ${\mathrm{m}}\bigl(\arc{AQ}\bigr) = {\mathrm{m}}\bigl(\arc{BQ}\bigr)$. So,
\begin{equation*}
{\mathrm{m}}\bigl(\arc{AP}\bigr) = 180 - {\mathrm{m}}\bigl(\arc{AQ}\bigr) = 180 - {\mathrm{m}}\bigl(\arc{BQ}\bigr) = {\mathrm{m}}\bigl(\arc{BP}\bigr) .
\  \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{equation*}

The following code can be compiled by `TikZ` to render a diagram associated with this argument.

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[name path=circle] (O) circle (2);

%Points A and B are drawn on the circle. Radii $\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{OB}$ are drawn.
\coordinate (A) at (180:2);
\node at ($(A)!-3mm!(O)$){$A$};
\coordinate (B) at (70:2);
\node at ($(B)!-3mm!(O)$){$B$};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (O) -- (A);
\draw (O) -- (B);

%The diameter of the circle is drawn through the midpoint M of $\overline{AB}$.
%The endpoints are labeled P and Q.
\coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);

%The label for M is typeset.
\coordinate (label_for_M_above) at ($(M)!1cm!(A)$);
\coordinate (label_for_M_right) at ($(M)!1cm!(B)$);
\path (label_for_M_above) -- (label_for_M_right);
\coordinate (midpoint_on_line_segment_to_position_M) at ($(label_for_M_above)!0.5!(label_for_M_right)$);
\node at ($(M)!4mm!(midpoint_on_line_segment_to_position_M)$){$M$};

%The diameter $\overline{PQ}$ is drawn.
\path[name path=path_to_locate_P] (M) -- ($(M)!3.5cm!(O)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_to_locate_P and circle, by=P}];
\node at ($(P)!-3mm!(M)$){$P$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);

\path[name path=path_to_locate_Q] (M) -- ($(M)!-1cm!(O)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_to_locate_Q and circle, by=Q}];
\node at ($(Q)!-3mm!(M)$){$Q$};

\draw (P) -- (Q);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at M.
\coordinate (U) at ($(M)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U) -- ($(M)!(U)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U) -- ($(M)!(U)!(A)$);

%The label for O is typeset.
\coordinate (label_for_O_above) at ($(O)!1cm!(B)$);
\coordinate (label_for_O_right) at ($(O)!1cm!(P)$);
\path (label_for_O_above) -- (label_for_O_right);
\coordinate (midpoint_on_line_segment_to_position_O) at ($(label_for_O_above)!0.5!(label_for_O_right)$);
\node at ($(O)!3mm!(midpoint_on_line_segment_to_position_O)$){$O$};

%Line segments $\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{OB}$ are marked with "|".
\draw ($($(O)!0.5!(A)$)!3pt!90:(O)$) -- ($($(O)!0.5!(A)$)!3pt!-90:(O)$);
\draw ($($(O)!0.5!(B)$)!3pt!90:(O)$) -- ($($(O)!0.5!(B)$)!3pt!-90:(O)$);

%Line segments $\overline{AM}$ and $\overline{BM}$ are marked with "||".
\draw ($($($(A)!0.5!(M)$)!1pt!(A)$)!3pt!90:(A)$) -- ($($($(A)!0.5!(M)$)!1pt!(A)$)!3pt!-90:(A)$);
\draw ($($($(A)!0.5!(M)$)!1pt!(M)$)!3pt!90:(A)$) -- ($($($(A)!0.5!(M)$)!1pt!(M)$)!3pt!-90:(A)$);
\draw ($($($(B)!0.5!(M)$)!1pt!(B)$)!3pt!90:(B)$) -- ($($($(B)!0.5!(M)$)!1pt!(B)$)!3pt!-90:(B)$);
\draw ($($($(B)!0.5!(M)$)!1pt!(M)$)!3pt!90:(B)$) -- ($($($(B)!0.5!(M)$)!1pt!(M)$)!3pt!-90:(B)$);

%The tangent line $\ell$ to the circle at P is drawn.
\draw[-latex] (P) -- ($(P)!3.5cm!90:(O)$);
\draw[-latex] (P) -- ($(P)!3.5cm!-90:(O)$);
\node at ($(P)!{3.5cm+0.3cm}!-90:(O)$){$\ell$};

%The angle mark for $\angles{AOQ}$ is drawn. It is marked with "|".
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(O)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(O)!0.4cm!(A)$) arc (180:{\n1+180}:0.4);
\draw[blue] let \p1=($(O)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(O) +({0.5*(180+(\n1+180))}:{0.4cm-3pt})$) -- ($(O) +({0.5*(180+(\n1+180))}:{0.4cm+3pt})$);

%The angle mark for $\angles{BOQ}$ is drawn. It is marked with "|".
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(O)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(O)!0.4cm!(Q)$) arc ({\n1+180}:70:0.4);
\draw[blue] let \p1=($(O)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(O) +({0.5*((\n1+180)+70)}:{0.4cm-3pt})$) -- ($(O) +({0.5*((\n1+180)+70)}:{0.4cm+3pt})$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

Comment: I suggest you insert a real picture instead of the code for a reader to do. Very few will actually compile it.

Comment: Why is that unusually awkward? It seems like that would be the straightforward approach...

Comment: @Michael Biro  I presented my own argument for the proposition.  The argument from the textbook was awkward.

Comment: @Michael Biro  Apparently you read my argument and understood it.  Any suggestions?  Did you compile the code with `TikZ`?

Comment: Ah, I see. I will post the version of this argument I was considering. I didn't compile the code, but the description was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this version of the approach might be a little bit simpler, although it is essentially the same idea.

By the inscribed angle theorem, the claim is equivalent to showing that $\angle ABP = \angle BAP$. This is in turn equivalent to showing that the perpendicular to $\mathit{l}$ through $P$ bisects $AB$.

So, take your line $k$ perpendicular to $\mathit{l}$ at $P$, and note (like you did) that $k$ goes through the center of the circle $O$ and is also perpendicular to $AB$. Now look at the triangle $OAB$. Since it is isosceles with base $AB$ that means that $k$ must bisect $AB$.

Comment: As I am teaching this course, I wanted to emphasize the definitions of angular measure.  I also wanted to remind students that the line perpendicular to a tangent to a circle and through the point of tangency contains the center of the circle.  (You did reference this in your argument.)  Thanks.